# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.v7.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

i'm using Android Studio.
When i'm tried to run my application i got the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.v7.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

My .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:fillViewport="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp">

    <android.support.v7.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email" />
    </android.support.v7.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My  compiled sdk version is 22.
Any suggestions please?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` without the `v7`.

Comment: Hi, same error..i see also the follwoing error:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.design.widget.TextInputLayout" its can help? ;\

Comment: Sorry. the other way round, remove the `v7`

Comment: the problem was solved when i'm change the first TextInputLayout to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Comment: @DavidMedenjak 
 
am using android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout but my app is clashing in api level 23 and above.! my `build.gradle` contains `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0' compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'` please help. users are uninstalling my app because of this error!

Answer (score 2):

It should not be

```
android.support.v7.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

It should be

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

Comment: am  using `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` but my app is clashing in api level 23 and above.! my build.gradle contains `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'` please help. users are uninstalling my app because of this error!

Comment: plz add your stacktrace @gikarasojokinene

Comment: see my entire question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/42789175/3671509